# Space Key Disabled in Form in Bootstrap Carousel Slide

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I have a form inside a Bootstrap carousel slide.  I can not enter spaces in the text boxes in the fields and cannot see why.  Here's my code:

```
<section class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false" data-wrap="false">
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
        <form class="form-inline" name="myForm">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input name="title" type="text" class="form-control" /> 
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-link">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
  </div>

</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can capture the spacebar keypress (code 32) and prevent the propagation to the carousel.

```
$('input').on('keydown', function (e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 32) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  }
});
```

I would also prevent keyboard navigation on the carousel or people using the arrows might navigate through carousel slides.

```
<section class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false" data-wrap="false" data-keyboard="false">
```

Live example: http://www.bootply.com/phVgpOYnO0

Comment: Excellent!  That works great.  How about if I have a content editable span in the slide?  I tried $('span'), but not go.

Comment: @CodeMonkey I see it working just fine on span. Is there maybe more information you can provide? http://www.bootply.com/FlZL8ZdFXz

Comment: Working with an angular object and another directive was blocking the span.  Thanks for the help!